# “Learn the ropes” when do we use this idiom?

Tags: idioms, sentence-usage, idioms-in-context

Can I use this idiom when I talk about “studying”?

For example:

> I’m going to Canada to study and **learn the ropes** of English.

It doesn’t seem right to me, but I don't know.

Comment: I wouldn't. "Learn the ropes" in my experience is always in relation to a new task, or set of tasks, not in relation to a general subject.

Comment: Learn the ropes or be shown the ropes is generally associated with skilled manual labour rather than academic learning.  I believe it`s an old naval term concerned with learning how to handle the ropes and lines.

Answer (score 3):

As a native speaker, I agree with *Colin Fine* and wouldn't use this.

*[Learn the ropes](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/learn+the+ropes)* is defined as:

> If you learn the ropes, you learn how to do a particular job or task.

It isn't really used in relation to a new language/subject.

I would say:

> I’m going to Canada to study and start **my learning experience** in English,

*learning experience* indicates you are new to English and fits well in your sentence.